# Environment specific shoryuken configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, amazon-sqs, shoryuken

I'm using the [shoryuken gem](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken) by running

```
bundle exec shoryuken -R -C config/shoryuken.yml
```

and shoryuken.yml is

```
concurrency: 25
delay: 0
queues:
- [development_high,  30]
- [development_mid,   6]
- [development_low,   2]
```

This works fine. However, I'd like to use the environment specific queues, e.g. use `production_high` in production. 
I make sure these queues exist in

`config/initializers/aws.rb` using

```
%w(low mid high).each do |q|
  sqs.create_queue(queue_name: Rails.env + '_' + q)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use a specific config `shoryuken.dev.yml` in development.

For the queues in development, I strongly recommend to create a user ([IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/)) per developer, with [the needed permissions](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/wiki/Amazon-SQS-IAM-Policy-for-Shoryuken) for the resource `"arn:aws:sqs:::${aws:username}-*"`, then in the config `- [<%= aws_user_name %>_queue_name, 1]`.

If you are using ActiveJob, have a look at the [`inline`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters/InlineAdapter.html) option. Might be an alternative.

Last but not least, you can also add queues at runtime, check [this](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/issues/282#issuecomment-282599455).

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround is using

```
concurrency: 25
delay: 0
queues:
- [<%=ENV['RAILS_ENV']%>_high,  30]
- [<%=ENV['RAILS_ENV']%>_mid,     6]
- [<%=ENV['RAILS_ENV']%>_low,     2]
```

and start shoryuken with

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec shoryuken -R -C config/shoryuken.yml
```